# regex to validate url starting with http|https|ftp or ending with .com|.tv

Tags: regex

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function create_urls(input)
    {
        var input = input.replace(/^((ht|f)tp(s?))\://([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\:[0-9]+)?(/\S*)?$/gim,'<a href="$&" class="my_link" target="_blank">$&</a>');
        document.getElementById('disply_id').innerHTML = input;
    } 
  </script>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
  <input type="text" id="replace_id"/>
  <input type="button" value="replace" onclick="create_urls(document.getElementById('replace_id').value);"/>
  <div id="disply_id">  
  </div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

i want to find url's matching with "http://google.com" or https://www.google.com and place it in anchor tag

Thanks

Comment: try to search for [regex] url in the search box on this page. I'm pretty sure one of these questions contains the answer which will help you for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from SELFHTML.org (German webpage) there's an [example](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/regexp.htm#dollar_1_9) doing pretty much the same.

```
var input= "foo bar http://google.com";
input = input.replace(/((ht|f)tps?:\/\/\S*)/g, '<a href="$1">$1<\/a>');
```

this will match every URL starting with http, https or ftp protocol.
To deal with the restriction on just `.com` and `.tv` endings you could try this:

```
input.replace(/((\S*\.(com|tv))(\/\S*)?)/gi, '<a href="$1">$2<\/a>')
```

combining both patterns you could be looking for something like this: *(some restrictions here)*

```
input.replace(/((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)?[^\/\s]+\.(com|tv))(\/\S*)?)/gi, '<a href="$1">$2<\/a>')
```

explained:

```
((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)?   - optional http:// or https:// or ftp:// or ftps://
[^\/\s]+             - URL domain containing no slash and no whitspace
\.(com|tv)           - ending .com or .tv (not optional! you may want to add more)
(\/\S*)?             - optional rest of URL after domain
```

P.S. In your regex you didn't escape the `//` by `\/\/`

***update***
I'd try this approach:

```
var regex = /((ht|f)tps?:\/\/\S*)/g;
var result = regex.exec(input);
if ( result != null && result.length > 1 ) {
  input = '<a href="' + result[1] + '">' + result[1] + '<\/a>';
} else {
  input = input.replace(/((\S*\.(com|tv))(\/\S*)?)/gi, '<a href="$1">$1<\/a>');
}
```

Comment: thanks bw_üezi for replying , the problem is that, i want to have regex validating (ht|f)tps OR (com|tv) , in any or both case it should be inserted into anchor tag

Comment: I split the replace `http....` using exec() where you can test if matches occure. the replace for `...com|tv` is only done if the first one didn't hit.